# How to integrat Swagger to my existing OAuth server spring boot application?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, swagger-2.0

We have OAuth2 server side application created with spring boot and i am beginner with swagger and i want to integrate it with my existing Oauth server App.

Comment: @snieguu,The answer you provided is correct but i would like to mention that the token generated by testing in postman,must pass through header in browser.

Comment: If the answer is correct please accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, now it is also available **Swagger 3.0**, formally knows as **OpenAPI Specification**, But You asking for **Swagger 2.0**. So, in my opinion, the best option is to use Spring Fox - https://springfox.github.io/springfox/
You only need to add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then create/reuse Spring configuration(Marked by `@EnableSwagger2` annotation), explained here:
http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#quick-start-guides

And then You can customize how swagger documents your controller in the way(eg `@ApiOperation` annotation):

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get user by id", httpMethod = "GET")
    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public APIUser getUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I am using Oauth2 which usually i test it's api's in postman because of token generated by our application is use to get call another api,how should do this?whatever u told above is i already did it.

Comment: Check this part of documentation http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#securing-swagger-ui